# Proving $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ge\sqrt{n}}$ with induction

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, radicals

I am just starting out learning mathematical induction and I got this homework question to prove with induction but I am not managing.

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ge\sqrt{n}}$$

Perhaps someone can help me out I don't understand how to move forward from here:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\ge \sqrt{n+1}}$$
proof and explanation would greatly be appreciated :)
Thanks :)

EDIT sorry meant GE not = fixed :)

Comment: You are going to have lots of problems proving that equality, for it is false. (Consider, for example, the case where $n=2$)

Comment: There is a typo somewhere : your first mathematical line is clearly wrong since $1 + 1/\sqrt{2} > 2$. Did you wish to prove the inequality, as your second line suggests?

Comment: The equality is false. If it were true, then $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ would equal $\sqrt{2}$. But $1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}$. If this were equal to $\sqrt{2}$, then you would have $2+\sqrt{2}=2\sqrt{2}$, or $2=\sqrt{2}$, which is patently false.

Comment: You can use the $\mathsf{Euler's \ summation \ formula}$. But as observed by in the previous comments, even I don't think that this is true.

Comment: Or maybe he just wants to prove $\ge$

Comment: @Chandra: If he is just learning mathematical induction, then he probably doesn't know Euler's summation formula.

Comment: @Gedgar: True. Sorry for the comments. I just suggested an another way of doing it.

Comment: There are plenty of elementary ways to do it, as Daniel suggested in his answer. OP doesn't need help in proving the statement in a general manner, he wants help on using induction to do it. Sure there are other ways. ^_^

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you wanted to prove that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{\sqrt k} \ge \sqrt n,
$$
that I can do. It is clear for $n=1$ (since we have equality then), so that it suffices to verify that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac 1{\sqrt k} \ge \sqrt{n+1}
$$
but this is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1{\sqrt k} + \frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}} \ge \sqrt{n+1} \
$$
and again equivalent to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt k} + 1 \ge n+1
$$
so we only need to prove the last statement now, using induction hypothesis. Since
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{\sqrt k} \ge \sqrt n, 
$$
we have 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt k} \ge \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n} \ge \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n} = n.
$$
Adding the $1$'s on both sides we get what we wanted.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Stylistic complaint: you end with «but this is $X\iff Y$», where you meant «but this is (equivalent to) $X$ which holds since $Y$» or something like that. As you wrote it, it appears that the inequality in your second equation *is* the same thing as a logical equivalence between two inecualities: this does not make much sense.

Comment: (After your edit, the same problem subsists: now «this is equivaent to $X\iff Y$» :) )

Comment: I was editing a lot : are there any complaints now? =)

Comment: I did not understand the last step could you please elaborate?

Comment: I multiplied the induction hypothesis by $\sqrt{n+1}$ to get the first inequality, and for the second inequality, since $n+1 > n$, $\sqrt{n+1} > \sqrt n$, so if you multiply those two by $\sqrt{n}$, you get $\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n} > \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n}$. That is $\sqrt{n}^2 = n$. Is that okay?

Comment: you still need to prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{k}}}$ is bigger then n though don't you?

Comment: That is what I proved. Using induction hypothesis I know that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{\sqrt k} \ge \sqrt n.
$$
Multiply both sides of my inequality by $\sqrt{n+1}$ and follow the steps from my last comment to prove that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{k}} \ge n.
$$

Comment: I see how you got to that inequity but what makes it true? (I feel stupid :P)

Comment: If you see how I got it then you see why it is true...

I assumed that what I wanted to prove was true up to $n$, so to show it is true at $n+1$, I assume it is true at $n$ (i.e. that the following inequality holds :
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{\sqrt k} \ge \sqrt n
$$
that is, induction hypothesis) and using this inequality I deduce that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt k} \ge n.
$$
To deduce it I use the steps above. Is that what you wanted me to clarify?

Comment: I Think I get it now :) Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: No problem! Anytime.

Answer (score 18):

A very short (though non-inductive) proof:

$$
  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \ge \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k-1}} = 
    \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1}}{(\sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k-1})(\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1})} = \sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1}) = \sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: Nice! Of course there is some hidden induction. [I'd put the $\sqrt k-\sqrt{k-1}$ in parenthesis in the last sum.]

Answer (score 16):

I won't use induction:

On the left side you have a sum with $n$ terms, the smallest one is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.
So you get the inequality:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+(n-1)\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)+\sqrt{n}$$

And now you can see easily that the right hand side is larger than $\sqrt{n}$, for all $n>1$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Couldn't you just write "greater than $n/\sqrt{n} = \sqrt n$" instead of keeping the $1/\sqrt{1}$ aside?

Comment: By the way, you can write \ge for $\ge$.

Comment: Thanks for $\ge$. Don't get your question right. You mean $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ge \frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}$$?

Comment: Exactly. Easier, isn't it?

Comment: @DDaniel: The induction is not explicit, though in fact there is an implicit induction hidden in the $\dots$.  Upvote for a probably simplest solution!

Comment: Daniel: so you proved the thing for every $n\ge2$ only... :-) (Corrected some typos in your answer, please look at the source to see the modifications.)

Comment: Daniel and @Didier: Nice job! I think it would also be better to remove "the equation:". ("Equation" suggests equalities, not inequalities, nor a combination of both.) (To Didier: entre deux mots, choisissons le moindre!)

Comment: Daniel: remains the odd treatment of the term $1/\sqrt1$, you could modify this part as well... (@Pierre-Yves: you are absolutely right, *equation* was simply inadequate there and I missed it.)

Comment: @Didier: Correct quotation: "Entre deux mots, il faut choisir le moindre." (Paul Valéry) [My suggestion was to write just "you get" (even without the colon (:)), because there is an inequality *and* an equality. (Whence the quotation). Sorry!]

Comment: @Didier: If I were the author, I'd put a period (.) at the end of the display. (You seem to do the same.)

Comment: @Pierre-Yves: I do (use periods where they are needed) but I seem to remember there is some debate about this when at the end of displays. Re "you get", I am not the one who did the last modification there; if I was I would have applied your suggestion.

Comment: @Didier: OK! I thought my suggestion wasn't clear enough (which would have made the quotation  impossible to understand). [A tougher exercise would be to translate the quotation into English ;)]

Answer (score 9):

You know that ${\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ge\sqrt{n}}}$, and your goal is to show that ${\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ge\sqrt{n+1}}}$. Observe that 
$$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}} + {1 \over \sqrt{n+1}}$$
$$\geq \sqrt{n} + {1 \over \sqrt{n+1}}$$
You use the induction hypothesis in the above line. So what you need to show is
$$\sqrt{n} + {1 \over \sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1}$$
At this point you can basically try to fool around with the algebra to get it to work out. One example of this would be to multiply both sides by $\sqrt{n+1}$, getting
$$\sqrt{n(n+1)} + 1 \geq n + 1$$
Or equivalently, 
$$\sqrt{n(n+1)} \geq n$$
Squaring both sides gives 
$$n^2 + n \geq n^2$$
This last equation is obviously true. To make the argument rigorous, you just observe that these steps are reversible; going in the opposite direction from above takes you from $n^2 + n \geq n^2$ to $\sqrt{n} + {1 \over \sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1}$.

Some people might not like doing this sort of reversal-of-steps argument, but it does have an advantage that you don't really have to see anything clever to do it; ususally playing around with the algebra enough will eventually lead to something obvious.

Comment: Great thanks, this is the solution I got to Though my algebra proof was different

Answer (score 7):

Using the same identity that Sasha did,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}\\
&\le\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}
\end{align}
$$
We can sum and multiply by $2$ to get
$$
2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}
$$
Which for most $n$ is stronger.

Comment: Can you give a characterization of the $n$'s for which is it stronger? =O Kidding. +1

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva: Any integer bigger than $\frac{16}{9}$

Comment: Lollll you guys are so serious. XD Anyway that's cool.

Comment: @Patrick Da Silva: I was joking, too, but maybe my sense of humor is off . o O (integer bigger than $\frac{16}{9}$...) :-p

Comment: I know it was a joke, that's why I added the XD in the end. If I had believed you were truly serious I would've been pissed.

Comment: Creative telescoping is always quite interesting (+1)

Answer (score 7):

For those who strive for non-induction proofs...

Since $\frac 1{\sqrt k} \ge \frac 1{\sqrt n}$ for $1 \le k \le n$, we actually have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{\sqrt k} \ge \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{\sqrt n} = \frac n{\sqrt n} = \sqrt n.
$$

Comment: This shows how understated the original estimate was. It's like saying that $\sum_{k=1}^n k\le n^2$.

Comment: I know... and it also shows why I'm so impressed that people made a huuuge deal about finding 430423 proofs for this.

Comment: @robjohn Talking of understated, I'm usually happy with $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} k = O(n^2)$. :-)