# Proof of an inequality: $\sqrt{n} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ge\sqrt{n}}$ with induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/proving-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-ge-sqrtn-with-induction)

How do I prove the following?
$$\sqrt{n} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}},$$ for all $n \in\mathbb{Z}$, $n\ge 2$.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{n}$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For any $r \in [1, n]$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \geqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$
with *strict* inequality for $1 \leqslant r \lt n$. Adding all these $n$ inequalities,
$$
\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} \gt n \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{n}.
$$

---

**Proof using induction.** The OP requested a proof using induction. I am assuming you can handle the base case $n=2$.

Now, assume that the inequality holds for some $n \geqslant 2$; we will verify the inequality for $n+1$: 
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} 
&= \sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}  
\\ &\gt \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} 
\\ &= \sqrt{n+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} - (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) 
\\ &= \sqrt{n+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}} 
\\ &\gt \sqrt{n+1} ,
\end{align*}
$$
which is what we want to show.

Notice that out second inequality is a bit too crude. robjohn's answer shows how to get a better bound by being more careful.

Comment: Is there any way to prove it using mathematical induction?

Comment: I am not sure why you would want an induction proof. Even if it were possible at all, it will definitely be only more difficult and less enlightening.

Comment: Yes, but if one does a routine induction the proof will look harder than the nice simple argument given by Srivatsan.  I can do one if you will promise not to accept it.

Comment: I have added an induction argument, @John.

Comment: @Srivatsan: with induction, you can get a better bound. However, for the bound requested, there is no reason to use induction.

Answer (score 11):

We can even do better:
$$
\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n-1}}\tag{1}
$$
Summing, we get
$$
\sqrt{n}-1<\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)\tag{2}
$$
So, for $n\ge2$,
$$
\sqrt{n}<1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)\tag{3}
$$
which is a better bound for every $n$.