# Prove by induction the following inequality for all n∈N

Tags: proof-writing, induction

$\frac1{\sqrt{1}} + \frac1{\sqrt{2}}+\frac1{\sqrt{3}}+...+\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\ge {\sqrt{x}}$

I proved the basic case: and realize it is equal to 1, but I have absolutely no idea how to create prove the left and right side using the induction hypothesis.

Please help :) I've solved equality's before using induction, but this is the first time I've done an inequality, and although I'm sure the process is fairly similar, I think the square root is messing me up.

Comment: What is the inequality? I see an equality in your question.

Comment: @MTurgeon, the OP edited out the entirety of the question, which indeed involved square roots.

Comment: @WillJagy : whatever the OP did, the title does not match the question.

Comment: @StefanSmith, the fourth edit says "posted wrong question." I have flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to fundamentally change the content after I have already answered your question. I find it extremely rude and disrespectful and have flagged this post for moderator attention.

Comment: @WillJagy : it's not a big deal, but I didn't see "posted wrong question" when I read it the first time, I don't see it there now, the title (with "inequality") does not match the question (which contains no inequality), and there is no square root in the question.  I don't really understand all the flagging business.  Thanks for flagging the question.  Somehow T. Bongers saw a version of the question that made sense.

Comment: @StefanSmith, click in the bottom middle of the question where it says, in light blue, 'edited 1 hour ago'  It should work for you, you have over 2000 points.

Comment: If you wish to ask another question, [ask another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/56335) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/88695).

Answer (score 2):

Let $s_n$ represent the sum up to $n$, and suppose that $s_n \ge \sqrt{n}$ for induction. We want to show that $s_{n + 1} \ge \sqrt{n + 1}$; to this end, note

\begin{align*}
s_{n + 1} - s_n &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}}
\end{align*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
s_{n + 1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}} + s_n \\
&\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{n + 1}} + \sqrt{n} \\
&= \frac{1 + \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n + 1}}{\sqrt{n + 1}} \\
&\ge \frac{1 + \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n + 1}} \\
&= \frac{n + 1}{\sqrt{n + 1}} = \sqrt{n + 1}
\end{align*}

as desired. The first inequality is by the induction hypothesis, and the second is just by noting that

$$\sqrt{n + 1} \ge \sqrt{n}$$

Comment: I am a bit confused. I have never seen this way. The way i am used is the base case and then deriving a proof. Is this is only way to do it?

Comment: @Jess The base case needs to be done in addition to the inductive step. I've only done the latter of the two.

Comment: @T.Bongers, see the edit history of the question. I have flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for letting me know :)

Comment: Well, because I was playing with it when it got erased, $s_n \approx -1.4603545 + 2 \sqrt {n + 0.5 }$