# Proving $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} > \sqrt{n}$ with induction

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, summation, induction, radicals

**Problem:** Prove with induction that \begin{align*} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} > \sqrt{n} \end{align*} for every natural number $n \geq 2$.

**Attempt at proof:** *Basic step:*  For $n = 2$ we have $1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} > \sqrt{2}$ which is correct.

*Induction step:* Suppose the assertion holds for some natural number $n$, with $n > 2$. Then we now want to prove that it also holds for $n +1$, i.e. that \begin{align*} \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} > \sqrt{n+1} \end{align*}
Now we have that \begin{align*} \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}  = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \end{align*} or \begin{align*} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > \frac{\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1} + 1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \end{align*}

Now I'm stuck, and I don't know how to get $\sqrt{n+1}$ on the right hand side. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can show $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n})$, you're done.

Comment: ... and to do so consider multiplying with $\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n$

Comment: Questions about the same inequality: [Proving $\sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>\sqrt{n}$ by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003136/proving-sumn-k-1-frac1-sqrtk-sqrtn-by-induction), [Proving $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ge\sqrt{n}}$ with induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/proving-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-ge-sqrtn-with-induction) and some other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/56335)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer points out in the comments, since you have 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}  > \sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
$$
it is enough to show
$$
\sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1}
$$
or equivalently $
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} 
$. A way to show this final inequality is to recall the identity $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2$ and multiply both sides by $\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}$, i.e. to use the identity with $a=\sqrt{n+1}$ and $b=\sqrt{n}$: what happens to the LHS? To the RHS?

Comment: I don't understand why it is enough to show that $\sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \geq \sqrt{n+1}$? How did you deduce that?

Comment: Because you proved half of it already, basically. Look at it this way: you want to show that $A > B$, and you proved so far that $A > C$. So if you manage to show that $C \geq B$, then you get $A > C \geq B$, and therefore in particular $A > B$ as you wanted.

Comment: I see. Ok, I did what you said. That gave me $(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}) (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}) \geq ( \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) ( \sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n})$. But if I distribute on the left side and simplify on the right side, I get $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} > 1$?

Comment: Which is indeed true as it can be simplified to $1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}>1$, so that the statement is proven (each inequality is equivalent to the previous one, and the last you get is true.)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that :

$ \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1} + 1 > \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n} + 1 $

$\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1} + 1 > n + 1 $

$ \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1} + 1 > \sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+1} $

$ \frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1} + 1}{\sqrt{n+1}} > \sqrt{n+1}. $