# Mathematical Induction Proof: $1/\sqrt1 + 1/\sqrt2+...+1\sqrt n \ge \sqrt n$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, radicals

I need the full proof/solution to this problem.

[image]

What I've done so far:

[image]

Comment: Please show us some effort. Also, try to search this site for similar questions. I think this one has been asked before.

Comment: OK, I will post what I've done so far. I think it's not completely correct.

Comment: Another way (not by induction) would be to observe $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\geq\frac{2}{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}}=2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)$.

Comment: sketchy move from second before last to before last .. those things arent equal

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/proving-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-ge-sqrtn-with-induction) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/56335).

Comment: Very classical looking handwriting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

suppose your formula is true for $n$,
Then $$\sum^{n}_{i=1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}}>\sqrt{n}$$
we then try to prove the formula true for $n+1$
$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\frac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\sqrt{n+1}$$

The base case is true so it's true for all n

Comment: how did you simplify sqrt(n) X sqrt(n+1) + 1 to n+1? Also, why is (n+1)/(sqrt(n+1)) = sqrt(n+1)?

Comment: 1) sqrt(n) is smaller than sqrt(n+1), so we can replace it and make the relation an inequality (meaning always bigger). Then the sqrt(n)^2=n

Comment: 2) a/sqrt(a)=a*sqrt(a)/a=sqrt(a)

Comment: shouldn't your summation have an upper bound of n instead of n+1?

Answer (score 5):

Multiply at both sides by $\sqrt{n}$. You get

$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{\sqrt{kn}}\geq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{\sqrt{nn}}=\sum_{k=1}^n1=n$

Comment: Or, more simply, with no multiplication by $\sqrt{n}$ nor any term $\sqrt{nk}$, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\geqslant\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** note that
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt n} \geq \sqrt n - \sqrt{n-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is basically OK except for near the end, where you write

$${\sqrt{k(k+1)}+1\over\sqrt{k+1}}={\sqrt{k+1}\times\sqrt{k+1}\over\sqrt{k+1}}$$

The "$=$" there should be a "$\ge$."