# EDIT: Why is $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, summation, radicals

Having problems with another inductive proof.. again with the algebra

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>\sqrt{n} :\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}, n>1$$

What I've done:

1. Proved for n=1
2. Showed I need to prove $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>\sqrt{n+1}$$
3. Attempt:
   $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
   $$\iff \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} $$

Again, I come no futher than this. I assume its something I don't know or can't see.

Cheers!

Andy

Edit: After being referred to another similar question, what I don't understand is why 
$$\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n+1}$$
which it obviously must be.

In the same vein, during my proof I didn't know (algebraically) to prove 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}>\sqrt{n}$$

If I put numbers in I can see that it is trivially true but not why it is generally true..

Comment: "What I don't understand": just multiply that inequality by $\sqrt{n+1}$ and all will become clear.

Comment: See [Proving $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\ge\sqrt{n}}$ with induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/proving-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-ge-sqrtn-with-induction) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/56335).