# Proving the series $s_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, induction

Let $s_n=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$. This sequence is definitely increasing, and I tried to show that it is not bounded above, by induction. However if $s_n\leq2$, then $s_{n+1}\leq2+\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\nleq2$. So I thought this is not bounded above.

Now, the second sequence is $s_n=\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}$. The problem requires to prove that this one is bounded above by $2$.

I tried to apply the same method as before: if $s_n\leq2$, then $s_{n+1}\leq2+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\nleq2$. But, this is bounded above by $2$.

What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: The same argument shows that no increasing sequence of positive numbers is bounded above by $2$, or by $3$, or by $4$, or by ...

Comment: If $a\le b$ and $c\ge0$, it does not follow that $a+c\not \le b$  (e.g., $2\le 4$ and $1\ge0$ and $2+1\le 4$) even though $a\le a+c$

Comment: That series is clearly larger than the harmonic series, which notoriously diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument indeed shows that $s_{n+1}\le 2+ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$, but that doesn't mean that $s_{n+1} > 2$ since if you have $s_{n+1}\le2$ then you certainly have $s_{n+1}\le 2+ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$.

As a hint for your problem, try starting with $s_n^2$ along with the fact that any sequence $a_n$ is bounded if and only if $\sqrt{a_n}$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with your logic?

Well, if $s_n\le 2$ and $s_{n+1}=s_n+c$ with $c\ge0$, that means $s_n\le s_{n+1}$,

but it does not mean $2\le s_{n+1}$.

In fact, for the second sequence, $s_1=1\le2$, and $s_2=s_1+\frac14=\frac54<2.$

Answer (score 1):

The statement

$$s_n\le2\implies s_{n+1}\le 2+\frac1{\sqrt n}\not\le 2$$

is

- not justified,
- false.

(Take $s_1=1$.)

But, what's worse, $>2$ does not mean unbounded at all

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the integral $S_n = \int_1^n \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$. Note that $(\sqrt{x})' = \frac 1 2 \frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ so your integral is infinite. Because the integrand is decreasing, you can compare 
$S_n$ and $T_n =  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$. This will actually show that for any positive strictly decreasing $f$, the integral

$$\int_1^\infty f(t)dt$$

is finite if and only if the infinite sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)$$
is finite.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing some ideas here. If you assume $s_n\le2$ and deduce $s_{n+1}\le2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$, this logic is correct (if you prove it for the **induction base** $s_1$ - this is called proof by **induction**). However, you did not prove that $s_{n+1}\ge 2$ - intuitively, you don't know "how much" smaller from $2$ is $s_n$, so adding $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ to it might still make it smaller than $2$, so you did not prove  that it is not bounded. As for your question, try looking at the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/proving-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-ge-sqrtn-with-induction).

For your second question, try using this inequality (which you should prove rigorously using induction):
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{4^2} +\frac{1}{5^2} +\frac{1}{6^2} +\frac{1}{7^2} +\frac{1}{8^2} +⋯ \\
&<\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2} +\frac{1}{4^2} +\frac{1}{4^2} +\frac{1}{4^2} +\frac{1}{8^2}+\dots \\
&=1+2⋅\frac{1}{2^2} +4⋅\frac{1}{4^2}+8⋅\frac{1}{8^2} +⋯ \\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+⋯ \\
&=2.
\end{align}$$

[Side note - this is a very interesting sequence. The infinite sum was unknown for more than a century, until Euler proved it is equal to the surprising value of $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ in 1734. This problem was called [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). Also check the very nice [3Blue1Brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls).]